# How can I get the polyphase components of a signal

Tags: matlab, digital-filters

My question, What is the polyhase components of the signal? What does mean a polyphase component for a signal?

Is it true that example :

```
N = 100;
h = firls(N, [0 .2 .25 1], [1  1 0  0],[.001 .0001]);

% PolyPhase Componets
%First polypase component 

for i=1:length(h),
h0(i)=h(i);
end

%% Second polyphase component 

for i=1:length(h),
h1(i)=h(i)*exp((-j*2*pi*((i-1)))/4);
end

%% Third polyphase component: 

for i=1:length(h),
h2(i)=h(i)*exp((-j*2*pi*(2*(i-1)))/4);
end

 and so on ..
```

Thank you

Comment: I removed the "digital-communications" tag, as it was totally unrelated. Please don't just randomly sprinkle tags on your questions, thanks!

Comment: OK, thank you so much .. I'm sorry because I don't know that is totally unrelated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not right:

Your polyphase components need to be ... well, phases of your signal, and hence, only take every $N$th component. What you do is something different.

To say "these are polyphase components of $h$", you need to define *how many* components you'll have. You're mixing different $N$s in your code, but overall, your code is just confused – it never selects the $N$th input samples.

Hence, you'd need something like

\begin{align}
p^4_0[n] &= h[4n]\\
p^4_1[n] &= h[4n+1]\\
p^4_2[n] &= h[4n+2]\\
p^4_3[n] &= h[4n+3]
\end{align}

for a $N=4$-phase polyphase decomposition of $h$ (of a specific type; "type" specifies in which order you take the $+0$,$+1$, $+2…$ components and declare them as $p_0$, $p_1$ and so on).

Feels like you need a better text book to start with! In English, the classic would be fred harris' *Multirate Signal Processing for Communication Systems*. It does an introduction that I'd explain differently these days, but I've worked with such systems a bit, and my initial understanding was guided by that book, so I consider it relatively good.

Comment: OK .. thank you so much dear, I will try to check that book of Multirate Signal Processing for Communication Systems and check if I can understand that well.

Comment: Please Marcus, 1- do you have MATLAB example for that components you mentioned above? or guide me how to build an example like that in MATLAB. 2-  By they way, I'm trying to check that book on-line but I didn't get it, do you have a link to download it, please.

Comment: 1 - no, this is a basic Matlab programming problem (slicing with a fixed step size), and if you can't solve this: read the very basic tutorial that comes with Matlab, 2- no.

Comment: Yes, got it.  When I understood the concept, I discovered that is very basic of MATLAB ... Thanks again